# Why won't my SearchEntry grow inside its SearchBar?

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, searchbar

I have a [`Gtk.SearchBar`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/SearchBar.html) with a [`Gtk.SearchEntry`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/SearchEntry.html) inside. I want the SearchEntry to use all the available (horizontal) space, so I set `entry.props.hexpand = True` and `entry.props.halign = Gtk.Align.FILL`. But for some reason the SearchBar won't grant it any extra space, and the Entry stays tiny.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

window = Gtk.Window()
window.set_size_request(800, 300)

search_bar = Gtk.SearchBar()
search_bar.props.search_mode_enabled = True
search_bar.props.show_close_button = True
window.add(search_bar)

entry = Gtk.SearchEntry()
entry.props.hexpand = True
entry.props.halign = Gtk.Align.FILL
search_bar.add(entry)

window.show_all()
window.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
Gtk.main()
```

You can tell from the size and location of the close button that the SearchBar does use all the space in the Window. But the SearchEntry just won't grow larger than its standard size. Why is this and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a simple solution, I have to apologize in advance for this answer. It's quite hacky, but it works. To start off, the `SearchBar` has a rather complicated child-widget setup. It looks like this:

```
Gtk.SearchBar
|   Gtk.Revealer
|   |   Gtk.Box (we will call this "main_box")
|   |   |   Gtk.Box (we will call this "box1")
|   |   |   Gtk.Box (we will call this "box2")
|   |   |   |   Gtk.SearchEntry
|   |   |   Gtk.Box (we will call this "box3")
|   |   |   |   Gtk.Button
|   |   |   |   |    Gtk.Image
```

The problem has it's root in a number of widgets here. Your solution is working, for the entry; the entry is expanding as far as it can. I'll explain the problems and their solutions, and then show the code at the end. The numbers are so that you can see which lines of code go with which solution steps.

1. The entry's parent box, `box2`, is not expanding as far as it can. So, you need to set `props.hexpand` and `props.halign` for it as well. This partially works, but there's still some extra space on the left and right of the entry.
2. To solve that, you need to remove `box1` from `main_box`, since it doesn't need to be there. Now, the entry expands all the way to the left, but there's still some space between the right of the entry and the button.
3. *That* is caused by `box3` expanding when it shouldn't. So you need to set `hexpand` for `box3` to `False`. This should fix the problem; your search bar's entry should expand the way you want it to, and the button should take up less horizontal space
4. (optional) If you don't want the button to expand vertically, you can put the `SearchBar` in a `VBox`, and put that `VBox` in the window. Note that you need to call `pack_start()` on the `VBox` for this to work: `vbox.pack_start(search_bar, False, False, 0)`.

Here is the relevant code (Step 4 is omitted). You can add this code underneath the line `search_bar.add(entry)`:

```py
# Get the correct children into the right variables
main_box = search_bar.get_children()[0].get_children()[0]
box1, box2, box3 = main_box.get_children()

# Fix the problem
box2.props.hexpand = True # See step 1
box2.props.halign = Gtk.Align.FILL # See step 1
main_box.remove(box1) # See step 2
box3.props.hexpand = False # See step 3
```

Comment: Wow, you just saved me a lot of time. I was going to experiment with overriding the methods responsible for assigning space to child widgets, but I didn't realize the searchbar had internal child widgets. Can I ask how you discovered this internal structure of the searchbar? I don't think it's documented anywhere, is it? I'm a bit hesitant to interact with these internal child widgets.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I discovered the structure by writing a recursive function that used widgets' `get_children()` method, and printed the children in an increasingly indented way. I never use the Gtk documentation (I don't even know where it is), and I don't really miss it, as I've heard that it's not very thorough; Python's `help()` function is really useful in these cases. Interacting with these child widgets is okay; it's exactly like interacting with all the widgets you create for your own window, except in a less-than-pretty way. If you want to see the function's code, I can put it in my answer.

Comment: @Aran-Fey :-D At this point, it would be just as efficient to write your own `SearchBar` class that handles things correctly! I'm really curious what `box1` is there for; it's completely empty, but it takes up otherwise-useful space. The reason I keep using GTK is that it looks best on my system (an Ubuntu); if it was as easy to use as [tag:tkinter], it would be a dream come true.

Comment: No that's fine, I just wanted to know if this was public knowledge or if you discovered it by slicing open Gtk's underbelly. I'll wait a while before I accept your answer just in case a better one comes along. I'm really not happy with this solution, but I'll use it if I have no other choice.

Comment: Yep, as a user I love Gtk, but as a programmer I loathe it.

Comment: @Aran-Fey No problem; I hope there is a better solution! I really enjoy problem-solving and coding, so the rep is less than 30% of the fun :-). I'm on here to learn and help others (and learn how to help others by helping others learn).